# foundation header instead of cocoa header for objective-c class (NSObject subclass)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, xcode4

in xcode 4, when i try to create a class, for example "ABClass" using a template for Mac OS X, the end result when the file created is:

```
//header
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface DBFTimer : NSObject {
@private

}

@end
```

and the other file

```
//.m file
#import "DBFTimer.h"


@implementation DBFTimer

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
}

return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

is this a bug? and what is the solution? (running Xcode 4 Build 4A304a)

EDIT: ok now i understand why, as this is an subclass of `NSObject`, thus the foundation header only is required.

Comment: Why do you think that class is for Cocoa Touch?

Comment: the class i selected was an objective-c class for cocoa on mac os x. the objective-c class for cocoa touch on iOS uses <Foundation/Foundation.h> instead of <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s a valid class for both Cocoa and Cocoa Touch. I believe recent versions of Xcode decide whether to import Cocoa/Cocoa.h or Foundation/Foundation.h based on what you’ve specified as the superclass. If the class you’ve created inherits from `NSObject`, there’s no need to import the whole of Cocoa — Foundation alone suffices.

Answer (score 0):

The example you've posted is a perfectly valid Mac OS X Cocoa class. (i.e.: There's nothing about that class that's iOS/Cocoa Touch related.)

In terms of your comment about iOS using `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` - this isn't the case - if you look inside `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`, you'll find that it actually includes the foundation header itself as well as other items such as CoreData, etc.